# Problem with updating prestashop via the 1-Click Upgrade module error Javascript error (parseJSON) detected for action upgradeNow"Starting restoration

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-helper-classes

I need to update prestashop from version `1.7.8.10` to `8.1.3`. the problem is that I get an error:

> Javascript error (parseJSON) detected for action upgradeNow"Starting restoration..."

the error pops up right after I press the update button. I use PHP 7.4, I will be very grateful for any help.

I tried changing PHP, turning off modules,